# unable to set up mongodb bi connector in docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, connector

Able to run bin/mongosqld from https://www.mongodb.com/products/bi-connector .

```
2019-07-18T21:54:07.313+0530 I CONTROL    [initandlisten] mongosqld starting: version=v2.11.0 pid=24664 host=Pavilion
2019-07-18T21:54:07.313+0530 I CONTROL    [initandlisten] git version: fa5c6ea06ca0092ed2f951af5be93c18383e1aa3
2019-07-18T21:54:07.313+0530 I CONTROL    [initandlisten] OpenSSL version OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016 (built with OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016)
2019-07-18T21:54:07.313+0530 I CONTROL    [initandlisten] options: {}
2019-07-18T21:54:07.313+0530 I CONTROL    [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for mongosqld.
2019-07-18T21:54:07.313+0530 I CONTROL    [initandlisten]
2019-07-18T21:54:07.443+0530 I NETWORK    [initandlisten] waiting for connections at 127.0.0.1:3307
2019-07-18T21:54:07.443+0530 I NETWORK    [initandlisten] waiting for connections at /tmp/mysql.sock
2019-07-18T21:54:07.461+0530 I SCHEMA     [sampler] sampling MongoDB for schema...
```

Not able to run it in docker

docker-compose file

```
dbs:
  build: .

  expose:
    - "4000"
  ports:
    - "4000:4000"
  command: node index.js
```

Establish connection between mongodb connector in docker

Comment: Please elaborate more. Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example while asking questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: @mchawre added it